# In JQuery, what does it mean to 'wire up' an object?

Tags: jquery

I have the task of 'wiring up' an input box and a submit button on a web page to allow a user to enter their own message. I am new to programming and was curious as to what the 'wiring up' part in JQuery means. Any advice or examples will help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Wiring up" simply means to attach the necessary event handlers to make it carry out the task.

Comment: Input box = Light bulb, Submit Button = Light switch. You need to wire 'em up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically means attaching something like a click event handler to and elemet in the DOM

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>

<script>
    $('.btn').click(function(){
         console.log('clicked');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would mean that you need to add the required javascript/jquery to "wire up" the input with the output(message). It should look something like this:

```
$(BUTTON_SELECTOR).on('click', function() {
       var input = $(INPUT_SELECTOR).val();        
       alert(input);
});
```